# How does one go about getting a .com .org .net account name and how do I get control of a dot domain wild card?

Tags: account-name, premium

I see that you can register a .com .net .org account name, but I read that you have to first control the account names com net and org in order to register these new ones. How does one get these 3 letter domain names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy and sell names on https://eosnameservice.io/

Answer (score 1):

Account names that are 3-11 characters long are considered premium account names. They get auctioned off daily on-chain. You can participate here:
https://toolkit.genereos.io/community/bidname

Once you have a premium account name, say `patoshi`, you own what we call the namespace. With the `patoshi` you will be able to create new accounts in the form `*.patoshi` assuming the account name is still less than 13 characters and only uses valid characters (a-z 0-5)

You'd need to reach out to the owner of the `com` account name to get access to `patoshi.com`. However many namespace owners sell account name in their namespace.

Comment: where does the money go to when someone wins an auction?

Comment: Right now it goes to the account `eosio.names`. There are plans to distribute these funds to token holders with the release of the Resource Exchange (REX).

Comment: https://eosflare.io/account/eosio.names -- that account has $7 million worth of eos. Who is sending the coins out from that account if its suppose to be for the REX?

Comment: Block producers